# Disable or Mock a background service in xunit .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, mocking, xunit

I have this line of code in my startup.cs in my project

```
services.AddHostedService<AkkaService>(sp => (AkkaService)sp.GetRequiredService<IEasyProcessor>());
```

I need to disable this line when I run my tests .I don't want use environment variable .I just need to mock or disable this service .
I Mock this service in my test solution like this :

```
    Mock<IEasyProcessor> easyprocessor= new Mock<IEasyProcessor>();

    services.AddScoped<IEasyProcessor>(processor =>{ return easyprocessor.Object; });
```

But I get this error :

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'Castle.Proxies.IEasyProcessorProxy' to type 'easy.api.Akka.AkkaService'.'
```

Comment: For a unit test, you don’t need to add the “services.AddScoped”. Your program.cs  will never be called anyway. Just keep the first line and then mock the setup of whatever function is in that interface.